# SharePoint mobile client development options

Tags: sharepoint

I have read through a [good](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313619.aspx) [amount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814.aspx) of [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx) and a few [blogs](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/sharepoint-2010-complete-details-about.html) and wanted to check my understand of the options for SharePoint mobile client development without requiring development on the SharePoint server itself.

SharePoint 2010

1. **Server Object Model**: Not applicable since code must run on SharePoint server.
2. **Client Object Model (JavaScript)**: Not applicable since cross-site scripting not allowed.
3. **Client Object Model (Managed .Net code)**: Possible, but would require an additional .Net server to communicate with SharePoint server. This new server could then serve JSON to mobile clients.
4. **RESTful**: Limited functionality, but unlike Managed Client Object Model, would not require an additional server.

SharePoint 2007

1. **Server Object Model**: Not applicable since code must run on SharePoint server.
2. **Deprecated SOAP web service**: Possible.

Questions:
Is this list exhaustive?
Are my summaries accurate?

Comment: Dear Jack, could you please help me out in the point 4 which you have mentioned regarding RESTful services. Is there any link or document which describes how to use the RESTful services in native iOS application and what are the different features that could be achieved using RESTful services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that for SharePoint 2007 there was a certain amount that could be done through FrontPage RPC calls as well. The Web Service interface was a trifle buggy and often incomplete, I'm not sure it was widely used and it certainly didn't seem well supported.

When I worked for a company that interfaced with SharePoint extensively we had our own web service that worked with the Server Object Model. Even that ran into problems as parts of the Object Model are not that well exposed and don't always seem that well understood even within Microsoft, but it was the only way to get a sufficient degree of remote integration with Sharepoint.

Comment: Interesting, but am I right in saying that even with your own Web Service, that using the Server Object Model with your custom service would require the service to be implemented on the SharePoint server?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. As SharePoint tends to be installed in a corporate environment that was never really a problem. Also, useful to be aware of: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com